# Define only certain files to be opened with certain software

Tags: notepad++, default-settings

I have some **.php** files, Some of them i want to be opened automatically by **notepad++**, So i go to properties then change the open with value, The problem is that all my **.php** files is now automatically opened with the software i defined, What i want to do is to define certain **.php** files to be opened automatically with certain software the **php engine** for example and some of them with the **notepad++**, The **first solution** i come up with is use the phtml suffix but it will be much more cleaner if i could choose the files i want to open with certain software, if anyone got a solution i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

notepad++  automatically adds a right click option to all files to open in notepad++.  leave php  files associated to the php  interpreter and just use the right click menu when you want to edit.

Comment: Thank you longneck, do you know where can i find available suffixes for php files such as .php/.phtml and more....